# text area from rails view returning null in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, codemirror

Rails 4. I have a view which has the following code in which I take input in a textarea  and want to apply code mirror modes to the code to text area 2. Unfortunately i am not able to read the contents of the text area 1. Even though i paste code in text area 1 and hit the submit button its always null when i receive it in my JS file.

categories/show.html.erb :

```
<div id="ccontainer">
<div class="hero-spacer">
  <%= text_area_tag :cols => "30", :rows => "10", :id => "myText", :class => "editor1-pane" %> 
  <%= text_area_tag :cols => "30", :rows => "10", :id => "myText2", :class => "editor2-pane" %>  

  <%= button_to_function "✓", '$(this).toggleClass("buttonGrey buttonGreen");', :class => "buttonGrey" %>
 </div>

 </div>
```

categories.js has :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $(".buttonGrey").on("click", function() {

       alert("Confirmed"+ $('#myText')); <--- Always returning null
       console.log($('.editor1-pane'));
       if(document.getElementById("myText").value == null){
           alert('NULL >>');
         }
       var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('myText'), {
            lineNumbers: true,
            matchBrackers: true,
            styleActiveLine: true,
            theme: "eclipse",
            mode: { name: "xml", htmlMode: true }
         }
       );
     // do something
       document.getElementById("myText2").value = myCodeMirror.getValue();
   }) 
 });
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is expecting `text_area_tag` to be followed by `name, content, options`, but you have just provided options.

So instead of assigning "myText" as the id, Rails is assigning your whole options list as the `name` (check your HTML output to see this) and not setting any of your options. Because of this your jQuery selector doesn't find anything.

Try this:

```
<%= text_area_tag "myText", nil, :cols => "30", :rows => "10", :class => "editor1-pane" %>
```

That should set the id and name of your text area to "myText" and set your options properly too.